# How do I hide sort icon by default and show by click on column header name

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanna to hide sorting icons by default and show them by clicking the column header name. This is my .cshtml code:

```
    @model string[]
<style>
</style>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <div class="tableHeader" id ="table">   
        <div class="card w-100 mb-1 border-0">
            <div class="card-dark-mode-body text-dark headerRow fw-bolder mainColor" >
                <div class="row p-2">
                    @foreach(var prop in Model)
                    {
                       
                        <div class="col text-center d-table sortable" >
                             <div class="btn-group" id="sorting" onclick="sortingVisibility()">
                            <p class="mb-0 d-lg-table-cell align-middle" id="columnName" style='padding-top:3px'>
                                @prop
                                <div class="btn-group-vertical" style='padding-left: 20px;' id="divIcon">
                                <a href="/Administracija/Ocitavanja/Index?OrderBy=@prop&Sorting=asc" class="btn btn-xs btn-link p-0">
                                    <i class="fa fa-sort-up" style='color:white;' id="sortUpIcon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </a>
                                <a href="/Administracija/Ocitavanja/Index?OrderBy=@prop&Sorting=desc" class="btn btn-xs btn-link p-0">
                                    <i class="fa fa-sort-down" style='color:white;' id="sortDownIcon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    @*<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom" style='color:white;'></span>*@
                                </a>
                                </div>
                            </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @*location.href='/Administracija/Ocitavanja/Index?OrderBy=@prop&Sorting=desc'*@
    <script>

       function sortingVisibility() 
        {  
            var iconUp = document.getElementById("sortUpIcon");
            var iconDown = document.getElementById("sortDownIcon");
            var div = document.getElementById("divIcon");  
            if (div.style.display !== "none") {  
                div.style.display = "none";
            }  
            else {  
                div.style.display = "block";
                
            }  
        }
```

I tried to do like this but its not working on click it only hide the  icon and doesnt change anything.
Can anyone give me some hints about this?

Comment: Any console output?

Comment: nah, on click it hide icons but no changes

Comment: What do the @ signs mean in your code?

Comment: do you mean @model? its model for displaying data in table

Comment: So you want to hide both `iconUp` and `iconDown` by default and want to show them both by clicking on the `div`?

Comment: Yes exactly can you give me some hints

Answer (score 1):

In order to hide the div, you have to initially set the **display property** of the div to **none** and then we have to set the display property to **block** or **none**.
Below I have modified your code with the changes.

```
 @model string[]
<style>
</style>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <div class="tableHeader" id ="table">   
        <div class="card w-100 mb-1 border-0">
            <div class="card-dark-mode-body text-dark headerRow fw-bolder mainColor" >
                <div class="row p-2">
                    @foreach(var prop in Model)
                    {
                       
                        <div class="col text-center d-table sortable" >
                             <div class="btn-group" id="sorting" onclick="sortingVisibility()">
                            <p class="mb-0 d-lg-table-cell align-middle" id="columnName" style='padding-top:3px'>
                                @prop
                                <div class="btn-group-vertical" style='padding-left: 20px;' id="divIcon">
                                <a href="/Administracija/Ocitavanja/Index?OrderBy=@prop&Sorting=asc" class="btn btn-xs btn-link p-0">
                                    <i class="fa fa-sort-up" style='color:white; display: none' id="sortUpIcon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </a>
                                <a href="/Administracija/Ocitavanja/Index?OrderBy=@prop&Sorting=desc" class="btn btn-xs btn-link p-0">
                                    <i class="fa fa-sort-down" style='color:white; display: none' id="sortDownIcon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    @*<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom" style='color:white;'></span>*@
                                </a>
                                </div>
                            </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @*location.href='/Administracija/Ocitavanja/Index?OrderBy=@prop&Sorting=desc'*@
    <script>

       function sortingVisibility() 
        {  
            var iconUp = document.getElementById("sortUpIcon");
            var iconDown = document.getElementById("sortDownIcon");
            var div = document.getElementById("divIcon");  
              if ( iconUp.style.display == "none" ||  iconDown.style.display == "none";){
                iconUp.style.display == "none";
                iconDown.style.display =="block";
            } else {
                iconUp.style.display == "block";
                iconDown.style.display =="none";
            }
        }
```

Comment: The following code hide icons by default, when I click on column header it only shows icons in first column.. kinda weird, what I wanna to achive is that on first click on column header sort by desc and show icon down and on second click to give me back sorted by asc and icon up :)